# Unable to restart docker container with restart ''always''

Tags: python, apache, docker, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I had tried all the ways but unable to restart my docker container .If used --restart "always" it goes in to infinite loop of restarting .

Below is the configuration of Dockerfile:-

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:4.4.0
EXPOSE 8000
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 \
    apache2-dev \
    vim \
 && apt-get clean \
 && apt-get autoremove \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
WORKDIR /var/www/test/
COPY ./test.wsgi /var/www/test/test.wsgi
COPY ./Demo /var/www/test/
RUN /opt/conda/bin/mod_wsgi-express install-module
RUN mod_wsgi-express setup-server test.wsgi --port=8000 \
    --user www-data --group www-data \
    --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80
CMD /etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl start -D FOREGROUND
```

and  is run the container using below command:-

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --restart always test1
```

after restart of docker/server

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                  NAMES
f4ec5dc90809        test1                 "/usr/bin/tini -- /b…"   2 minutes ago       Restarting (0) 26 seconds ago                          practical_colden
```

I had tried  on-failure also but not good result.

Logs of container

```
/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl: line 63: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
httpd (pid 7) already running
/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl: line 63: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
httpd (pid 7) already running
/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl: line 63: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
httpd (pid 7) already running
```

Comment: Try to generate locales: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454260/how-to-solve-locale-problem

Comment: Still Getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is the running (unfortunately incomplete) command `"/usr/bin/tini -- /b…"` looking at the source image Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/dockerfile that is the defined entrypoint. You could change your last `CMD` to an `ENTRYPOINT` of for testing start the docker container with `docker run --entrypoint $your-command -p ...` and see if it works